# Solve.Ivp Returning Intermediate Variables

Tags: python, modeling, differential-equations

I am looking for some help on solve.ivp. Currently, the way solve.ivp is currently set up, is that it returns the differentials to be used in solve ivp. However, for the purposes of my research, I will need to return the intermediate variables that are used within the model code as well.

I have tried creating an empty list, and then appending the values created by the model to the list at certain time points, however, for some unknown reason this results in way too many time points being produced and initial values of the intermediate variables being ignored. (I.e, I'm starting body weight at 60gs but the data my method provided starts it way lower, and I only want data at time points at 1,2,3,4 and 5, but printing a len statement gives me 15 data values)

Any help in solving this issue, or if you have another completely different method to try and get the variables out model would be super helpful!

Also note this method provided here: [Is there a way to store intermediate values when using solve_ivp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57823091/is-there-a-way-to-store-intermediate-values-when-using-solve-ivp) will not work for me as I need the whole model under one function.

Here is the code I am running, (dictionaries provided)

```
thisdict = {
    "KS" : 0.01,
    "AiPc" : 0.273,
    "AePc" : 0.022,
    "CiPc" : 0.18,
    "CePc" : 0.023,
    "CAA0" : 0.70,
    "POB"  : 0.55,
    "BV" : 0.072,
    "GENDER" : 1.0,
    "SPECIES" : 1.0,
    "AIPV" : 0.550,
    "CIPV" : 0.50,
    "AEPV" : 0.0525,
    "AEPV" : 0.0525,
    "CEPV" : 0.063,
    }
```

```
Feeding = {
        "FEEDAGE0": 0.0,       
        "FEEDAGE1" : 7.0,      
        "FEEDAGE2" : 35.0,
        "FEEDAGE3" : 63.0,
        "FEEDAGE4" : 106.0,
    
        "FEEDDM0" : 0.880,         
        "FEEDDM1" : 0.874,         
        "FEEDDM2" : 0.89,         
        "FEEDDM3" : 0.90,          
        "FEEDDM4" : 0.90,         

        "FEEDCP0" : 0.210,         
        "FEEDCP1" : 0.203,        
        "FEEDCP2" : 0.187,        
        "FEEDCP3" : 0.180,         
        "FEEDCP4" : 0.170,         

        "FEEDCF0" : 0.0820,        
        "FEEDCF1" : 0.0860,        
        "FEEDCF2" : 0.0940,        
        "FEEDCF3" : 0.0873,       
        "FEEDCF4" : 0.090,         

        "FEEDME_KJG0" : 13.00,    
        "FEEDME_KJG1" : 13.30,    
        "FEEDME_KJG2" : 13.60,     
        "FEEDME_KJG3" : 13.70,    
        "FEEDME_KJG4" : 13.70,     

        "FEED_SIDAA0" : 0.90,     
        "FEED_SIDAA1" : 0.90,     
        "FEED_SIDAA2" : 0.90,     
        "FEED_SIDAA3" : 0.90,     
        "FEED_SIDAA4" : 0.90,     

        "FEED_SIDCF0" : 0.85,     
        "FEED_SIDCF1" : 0.85,     
        "FEED_SIDCF2" : 0.85,     
        "FEED_SIDCF3" : 0.85,    
        "FEED_SIDCF4" : 0.85,    

        "LYSDIET0" : 1.26,       
        "LYSDIET1" : 1.14,        
        "LYSDIET2" : 1.10,         
        "LYSDIET3" : 0.95,         
        "LYSDIET4" : 0.95,         

        "METDIET0" : 0.516,        
        "METDIET1" : 0.490,      
        "METDIET2" : 0.460,        
        "METDIET3" : 0.30,         
        "METDIET4" : 0.30,         

        "DROPVALUE" : 0.97,        

        "MVCO2" : 1.87,        
        "MVO2" : 1.35,         
        "NH2AANH2" : 1.4,     


        "AIEAA" : 6.5,        
        "ECOST_DEAMINATION" : 2.2,     

   

        "AY_AA" : 2.5,         
        "AY_FA" : 9.0,         
        "AY_GL" : 2.0,         
        "GL_AA" : 0.83,        
        "GL_FA" : 2.67,        
        "GL_TG" : 0.5,         
        "FA_TG" : 3.0,          
        "FA_AY" : 0.102,        

        "CO2_GLAY" : 2.0,         
        "CO2_AYCO2" : 2.0,        
        "O2_GLAY" : 2.0,          
        "O2_AYCO2" : 2.0,        

        "ATP_AAAY" : 14.0,          
        "ATP_FAAY" : 36.0,          
        "ATP_GlAY" : 14.0,          
        "ATP_AYFA" : 1.13,          
        "ATP_LCFA" : 2.26,          
        "ATP_AYCO2" : 12.0,         

        "ATP_LA" : 10.0,            
        "ATP_PA" : 5.0,             
        "ATP_PC" : 1.0,             

        "ATP_FDFA" : 2.15,         
        "ATP_AUUN" : 14.36,        

        "EATP_kjmol" : 79.5,  

        "EGL_KJG" : 15.7,      
        "EL_KJG" : 39.6,       
        "EP_KJG" : 23.8,      

        "ELD_KJG" : 56.0,       
        "EPD_KJG" : 50.0,      

        "KF" : 0.96,          
        "KP" : 0.65,         
        "KOX" : 0.02,         

        "MMAA" : 125.0,          
        "MMCO2" : 48.0,          
        "MMFA" : 282.0,          
        "MMGL" : 180.0,          
        "MMN" : 14.0,            
        "MMNH2" : 16.0,          
        "MMO2" : 32.0,           
        "MMTG" : 884.0,          
    
    }
```

```
IBODYWT_G = 60.0
#This is the inital empty lists
BodyWt_g_S  = []
t_S = []

def Broiler_model(t, pools,):

    #globals are being used here in attempt to sneak intermediate variables out of the model
    global ADG_gd
    global BodyWt_g
    global Pc
    global Pv
    global dAAdt
    global i
    global BodyWt_g_S
    global t_S
    global PredFI
    global FaaPc_AA


    # this if else statement provides a counter to try and get unintegrated values out of the model at certain points
    if t == 0:
        i = 0
        BodyWt_g = 60.0
    else:
        if np.any(t == times2):
            i =+ 1

    Pred_FI = 80.0
    FaaPc_AA = 0.001
    #this is where I tried setting body weight to 60 at t==0 but it doesn't work
    if t == 0.0:
        BodyWt_g = 60.0
    
    

    Pc, AA, Pv, = pools
    
    #dont worry about this, this is just a feeding program
    if ( (t >= Feeding.get("FEEDAGE0")) & (t < Feeding.get("FEEDAGE1")) ):
        feedCP = Feeding.get("FEEDCP0")
        feedCF = Feeding.get("FEEDCF0")
        feedME_KJg = Feeding.get("FEEDKJG0")
        feedDM = Feeding.get("FEEDDM0")
        SIDAA = Feeding.get("FEED_SIDAA0")        # standardized ileal dig of AA, %
        SIDCF = Feeding.get("FEED_SIDCF0")        # standardized ileal dig of CF, %
        LYSDIET = Feeding.get("LYSDIET0") 
        METDIET = Feeding.get("METDIET0")
    elif ( (t >= Feeding.get("FEEDAGE1")) & (t < Feeding.get("FEEDAGE2")) ):
        feedCP = Feeding.get("FEEDCP1")
        feedCF = Feeding.get("FEEDCF1")
        feedME_KJg = Feeding.get("FEEDME_KJG1")
        feedDM = Feeding.get("FEEDDM1")
        SIDAA = Feeding.get("FEED_SIDAA1")       # standardized ileal dig of AA, %
        SIDCF = Feeding.get("FEED_SIDCF1")        # standardized ileal dig of CF, %
        LYSDIET = Feeding.get("LYSDIET1")
        METDIET = Feeding.get("METDIET1")
    elif ( (t >= Feeding.get("FEEDAGE2")) & (t < Feeding.get("FEEDAGE3")) ):
        feedCP = Feeding.get("FEEDCP2")
        feedCF = Feeding.get("FEEDCF2")
        feedME_KJg = Feeding.get("FEEDME_KJG2")
        feedDM = Feeding.get("FEEDDM2")
        SIDAA = Feeding.get("FEED_SIDAA2")      # standardized ileal dig of AA, %
        SIDCF = Feeding.get("FEED_SIDCF2")    # standardized ileal dig of CF, %
        LYSDIET = Feeding.get("LYSDIET2")
        METDIET = Feeding.get("METDIET2")
    elif ( (t >= Feeding.get("FEEDAGE3")) & (t < Feeding.get("FEEDAGE4")) ):
        feedCP = Feeding.get("FEEDCP3")
        feedCF = Feeding.get("FEEDCF3")
        feedME_KJg = Feeding.get("FEEDME_KJG3")
        feedDM = Feeding.get("FEEDDM3")
        SIDAA = Feeding.get("FEED_SIDAA3")     # standardized ileal dig of AA, %
        SIDCF = Feeding.get("FEED_SIDCF3") # standardized ileal dig of CF, %
        LYSDIET = Feeding.get("LYSDIET3")
        METDIET = Feeding.get("METDIET3")
    elif ( (t >= Feeding.get("FEEDAGE4"))  ):
        feedCP = Feeding.get("FEEDCP4")
        feedCF = Feeding.get("FEEDCF4")
        feedME_KJg = Feeding.get("FEEDME_KJG4")
        feedDM = Feeding.get("FEEDDM4")
        SIDAA = Feeding.get("FEED_SIDAA4")       # standardized ileal dig of AA, %
        SIDCF = Feeding.get("FEED_SIDCF4")      # standardized ileal dig of CF, %
        LYSDIET = Feeding.get("LYSDIET4")
        METDIET = Feeding.get("METDIET4")
    
    #some constants that need to calcuelated

    DMI = Pred_FI * feedDM

    plasma_vol = thisdict.get("BV") * thisdict.get("POB") * BodyWt_g/1000.0   # blood volume in L (JE)

    cAA = AA /plasma_vol      # conc of amino acids (JE)
    
    #FSRPC Variables
    n1 = 0.12713
    CPM1 = 1.99642
    Tcaa1 = 1.0 + ((CAA0/cAA) ** n1)

    #FSRPC Variables
    n2 = 1.0
    CPM2 = 1.19385
    Tcaa2 = 1.0 + ((CAA0/cAA) ** n2)

    FSRPc = thisdict.get("KS") + thisdict.get("AiPc") * (math.exp(-1.0 * thisdict.get("AePc") * t)) * (CPM1/Tcaa1)      #new/cut out of other eqn
    #fractional synthesis rate for carcass protein, /d (JE)#
    FDRPc = thisdict.get("KS") + (thisdict.get("CiPc") * math.exp(-1.0* thisdict.get("CePc") * t) * (CPM2/Tcaa2))
    #fractional degradation rate for carcass protein, /d (JE)    #new/cut out of orig eqn

    FaaPc_AA1 = FSRPc * Pc
    
    #Outputs
    #----------------------------------------------

    FPcAA_AA = FDRPc * Pc

    dPcdt = FaaPc_AA1 - FPcAA_AA
    
    n3 = 0.124593
    CPM3 = 0.1999848
    Tcaa3 = 1.0 + (CAA0/cAA) ** n3

    n4 = 0.124593
    CPM4 = 1.9999848
    Tcaa4 = 1.0 + (CAA0/cAA) ** n4
    

    # Auxillary
    #----------------------------------------------
    FSRPv = thisdict.get("KS") + (thisdict.get("AIPV") * (math.exp(-1.0 * thisdict.get("AEPV")) * t)) * (CPM3/Tcaa3)
    #   fractional synthesis rate for visera protein, /d (JE added)
    FDRPv = thisdict.get("KS") + (thisdict.get("CIPV") * (math.exp(-1.0 * thisdict.get("CEPV")) * t)) * (CPM4/Tcaa4)
    #   fractional degradation rate for viscera protein, d (JE added)

    # Inputs
    #----------------------------------------------

    FAAPvPv1 = FSRPv * Pv         # (JE)

    # Outputs
    #----------------------------------------------
    
    FPvAA_AA = FDRPv * Pv


    # Differential equation
    #----------------------------------------------
    dPvdt = FAAPvPv1 - FPvAA_AA    #(limAAfactor routine removed)


    #AA POOL
    # inputs
    #----------------------------------------------------

    Fdiet_AA = feedCP * Pred_FI * SIDAA
    
    FPcAA_AA = FPcAA_AA

    # Outputs
    #----------------------------------------------------

    FAAPc_AA = FaaPc_AA
    
    FIE_AA = Feeding.get("AIEAA")*(DMI/1000.0)

    dAAdt = FPcAA_AA + Fdiet_AA + FAAPvPv1 - FAAPc_AA - FIE_AA - FPvAA_AA

    Carcass = Pc + Pv
    BodyWt_g = Carcass

    #Here is where I append the variables that increased as counter goes up

    if np.any(t == times2):
        BodyWt_g_S.append(BodyWt_g)
        t_S.append(t)

    return [dPcdt, dAAdt, dPvdt,]






#Initial Values
CAA0 = 0.70
ieBW = IBODYWT_G * 0.87
Pc0 = 0.752 * ieBW * 0.263
AA0 = 0.002
Pv0 = 0.185*ieBW*0.263 


Y1 = [Pc0]
Y2 = [AA0]
Y3 = [Pv0]

#These contain varibles the model setup, that allows me to control timestep I THINK
# times2 can also be found here
start_t = 0
end_t = 5
times2 = np.linspace(start_t,end_t, num = end_t + 1)
time_step = 1e-3 #Time step you choose
times = np.linspace(start_t,end_t, int(end_t/time_step)+1)
tsymb = sp.symbols('t')
ysymb = sp.symbols('y')
for i in range(start_t,end_t,1):

    for j in range(0,int(1/time_step),1):
        tstart = i + j*time_step
        tend = i + j*time_step + time_step
        Y0 = [Y1[-1],Y2[-1],Y3[-1],]
        answer = solve_ivp(lambda tsymb,ysymb : Broiler_model(tsymb,ysymb,), (tstart,tend,), y0=Y0, method = 'RK45', t_eval=(np.linspace(tstart,tend,1000)),)
        Y1.append(answer.y[0][-1])
        Y2.append(answer.y[1][-1])
        Y3.append(answer.y[2][-1])
```

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49340376/is-it-possible-to-export-additional-variables-from-within-an-ode45-function, there is not really a nice way to solve this problem, and for more attempts at this situation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54304236/how-may-i-get-more-values, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34614272/matlab-export-changing-variable-with-ode45

Comment: Hey there! Thanks for responding, and for all the links, the first one seems promising and maybe what I am looking for. When I come up with a solution I will post it.